# Multiple Conditions Microsoft Flow

Tags: power-automate

How can i combine two conditions on a single condition step in Microsoft flow. I need it to check for a field that is null and to check creation date after 60 days. I tried this with two conditions but it does not seem like it is combining the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch your condition to "Edit in advanced mode" then
You can try something like:

`@or(equals(...)`

then pass your conditions into it.
An easy way to get what your condition will look like is by selecting your conditions first then switch to "Edit in advanced mode".